# How do I grab info from source code from other site?

Tags: html, copy

Is there a way to grab things out of the source code of another site directly into your site?

For example, let's say than in a site the following source code exists:

```
<table ...>
            <tr>
              <td class=...>...</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class=....><div align="... class=...>"Interesting string that keeps changing"</div></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

And we want that Interesting string that keeps changing to appear in our website as well.

Comment: Note that this is not a code, it's content, and you might be getting yourself into potential copyright troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use php

you use

$html = file_get_contents('url to website');

or use a hidden if you want a javascript function, and then just grab the innerhtml

Comment: Seems to work fine, but is there a way to copy only a part of the page, or should I cut the String I get from `file_get_contents`?

Comment: is the html always the same from the site you read the html from

cause then you can use 4th and 5th parameter to set offset and how much it should read

Comment: Good to know, but no, only a part of it remains the same. Still I'll get the whole thing, then trim the useless parts out. Also I'm getting a rather annoying "Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: stream does not support seeking"...

Comment: `<?php $selection = file_get_contents('http://****',NULL, NULL, 17411, 20); echo $selection; ?>`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out by using a few more functions:
`$selection = file_get_contents('http://****'); 
  $pos = strpos($selection,"class=...>"); 
  echo substr($selection,$pos + 9, 4);`
Thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome but if you had filegetcontents working you save it from reading the entire page